# In SQL, I would like to update specific rows to a new value

Tags: sql-server

With using a SQL database, I wanted to update a column (`nonexcludedsites`
in table (`workflowoutputcadas`) to a specific value for certain rows (40-50). What I did was this:

```
update workflowoutputcadas
set nonexcludedsites = 1
FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS Row, 
        nonexcludedsites 
    FROM workflowoutputcadas) AS w
WHERE Row between 40 and 50
```

So for this example, what I wanted is that I wanted rows 40-50 to be updated to 1 and the rest to be the same. When I ran script, it ended up updating the whole column to 1 which is not what I wanted to do. Do you know where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Is `row` a column  in your table?

Comment: well, you should've used `UPDATE w` instead

Comment: No, Row is not a column on my table.

Answer (score 1):

what about this way:

```
;WITH CteData
AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS [Rows], 
        nonexcludedsites 
    FROM workflowoutputcadas
)
update CteData
set nonexcludedsites = 1    
WHERE [Rows] between 40 and 50
```

Answer 2:

```
USE YourDatabase
GO
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS [Rows], 
    nonexcludedsites INTO #Temp
FROM workflowoutputcadas
GO
UPDATE workflowoutputcadas
set nonexcludedsites = 1   
FROM workflowoutputcadas INNER JOIN #Temp ON #Temp.nonexcludedsites = workflowoutputcadas.nonexcludedsites
WHERE #Temp.[Rows] between 40 and 50
GO
DROP TABLE #Temp
```

I'm assuming nonexcludedsites is a field you can use for relation

Comment: I was getting this error when i read that:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 5:         OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS [Rows], 
                                                    ^
********** Error **********

Comment: weird, please try again I just added the ";" at the begining of the WITH statement

Comment: Ya I tried it with and without the ";" but still gives me an error.
with ";" it gives me:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 5:         OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS [Rows], 
                                                    ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
SQL state: 42601
Character: 93

without:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 5:         OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS [Rows], 
                                                    ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "["
SQL state: 42601
Character: 92

Comment: right click over the SQL instance=>properties=> send values for product and version

Comment: im using pgADmin III to access the sql server..not sure if i can do that.

Comment: @user2128119 Execute the following query to know the version of SQL Server: `SELECT @@VERSION;`

Comment: Didnt work,ERROR:  column "version" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT @@VERSION
                 ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "version" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 10

Comment: Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update workflowoutputcadas
set nonexcludedsites = 1
FROM
workflowoutputcadas a --****
LEFT JOIN --****
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS Row, 
        nonexcludedsites 
    FROM workflowoutputcadas) AS w
on a.nonexcludedsites = w.nonexcludedsites --****
WHERE Row between 40 and 50
```

I've added commented-out asterisks to mark the lines that I've added to your original query.

Alternatively, you can use two subqueries, but it starts to get messy:

```
update workflowoutputcadas
set nonexcludedsites = 1
where nonexcludedsites in
    (Select nonexcludedsites from
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY nonexcludedsites) AS Row, 
        nonexcludedsites 
    FROM workflowoutputcadas) AS w
WHERE Row between 40 and 50)
```